# Progressive Streaming Videoplayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am developing an application in which I have a list of videos to be downloaded from the URLs. Each video is of about 10 min duration. Now, what I want is that the video is downloaded progressively in background and similarly displaying the downloaded video as like in Youtube.

I have tried using `VideoView` but it cant succeed.

So is it possible to do such with help of android's `VideoView`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/ shall help you. Would comment, but I can't.

Comment: That blog only says about audio streaming, if i follow same approach for video then it is not possible.To check whether progressive streaming works for video, i wrote a sample app where i will donwload half video and start playing downloaded content. But VideoView or MediaPlayer says **can't play this video**. I think we can't just directly deal with video staright away by geting only half of its byte content.